# How to enable ThisOutlookSession in Outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, outlook

If I put there any code, it is just not executed (looks like some security settings?). Tried to disable macro verification in the Trust Center - it doesn't help.

Code I've tried to use: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175110.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176426.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing your security settings, restart Outlook.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-documents-HA010031071.aspx#BM13

You'll also want to self-sign your VBA project using the self-cert tool included with Office. After doing so, restart Outlook and you should see a dialog asking you to "trust" the project.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah - you need to restart after changing the security settings.
In outlook 2013 : File_Options_trust center