# Outlook rules, perhaps with VBA

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I've been having some trouble with setting up rules in outlook. The reason for my issue is that the outlook rule definitions and conditions seem not capable enough.

What I want to do.
I get automated messages from a ticketing systems with a subject like "comments added" when ever someone replied to my e-mail inside the system.

I want to:

1. Move those items into a specific folder.
2. Add 2 categories
3. play a notification sound,
4. Flag it to follow up today,

Now, using rules, Whenever I complete a task and a new e-mail from that system comes in. That rule will run again and Flag all the completed tasks again.
But I want to make an exception for mails which are already flagged as completed.

Is it possible?
I was thinking about using VBA. Perhaps someone here has some pointers as to where I could start?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use VBA in Outlook. You could do something like this, which will allow you to process a new message when it comes in with a reply.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Folder = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
  Set Items = Folder.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
  ProcessNewMessage Item
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub ProcessNewMessage(NewMail As Outlook.MailItem)
    'DO WHAT YOU NEED TO WHEN NEW MAIL ARRIVES HERE
    'E.G
    'MsgBox NewMail.Subject
End Sub
```

You just need to program what to do when the message arrives. Check what the subject contains etc.

Comment: Ok I have tried something out. Though since no new mail has been received since I have set it up. 
The only thing what I wonder about is how this is called?
I mean, I had to create it as a class module in order to not give me errors.

But is this class Called automatically or do I need to create a regular module to call it?

Comment: This code should be added into the Module called ThisOutlookSession. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660028/how-to-enable-thisoutlooksession-in-outlook-2007